# A Fantasy-ish satire book

Tags: story-identification

I am trying to identify the title and author of a fantasy-ish satire book. It was a YA book, I think published in the last 10 years.

It is the main character's senior year of high school, and then some sort of supernatural thing begins, and deers begin freaking out and wreck the main character's car. While all this is happening, a new guy arrives at the school. At some point a concert stage explodes, and chaos ensues. A lot of people die mysteriously and a bridge gets spray-painted. All the adults behave really weirdly (except for 2-3) while a political race happens. Freak lightning suddenly begins to strike, then, on prom night, a bunch of things happen which lead to the school burning down. Ends with people swimming in a lake.

Characters:

- Mike (main character),
- A few people named Finn,
- Satchel,
- Aquamarine,
- Lincoln,
- Madison,
- Hannah (but spelled differently),
- John/Jared/Jacob,
- Mel or something like that,
- A few doctors,
- Mary???,
- two politicians,
- Malcolm,
- and some people whose names I cannot remember.

The title was some sort of cliche-y thing, and I think the cover was blue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [**The Rest of Us Just Live Here**](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/22910900-the-rest-of-us-just-live-here) by Patrick Ness. Characters include [Satchel, Finn, Aquamarine, Lincoln, Archie,](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=sVRpDQAAQBAJ&pg=PT78&lpg=PT78&dq=Finn,%20Satchel,%20Aquamarine&source=bl&ots=D-DWZtS3zE&sig=iQ51fkUprMA_RV5cKc_Iqzfgx_k&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiU4rmL6obUAhXIbFAKHdefAmcQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=Finn%2C%20Satchel%2C%20Aquamarine&f=false) etc etc

[image]